# WPPost error haveposts function is undefined

Tags: wordpress

[image: index.php]
[image: error]

The first post data is being posted but in the second iteration, I get an error in have_post() function.

Answer (score 0):

`$post->the_post();` sets a global variable called **$post**, overwriting your `$post` variable with a `WP_Post` object which causes the error you're seeing now.

Rename **every** instance of `$post` in your code to something else (eg. `$posts`) and it will work.